# Comparing specific characters in strings

Tags: python, string-comparison

```
s1="aaaaa"
s2="aa"
#expected output=3, because there is a "aa" in "aaaaa", at the 3rd position of s2
```

How do I find the last position where the characters match?

Comment: What's the expected output for the above example?

Comment: What is result that you want?

Comment: your question should be  "find index of all character in s1 which matches with all character in s2"

Comment: Wow, this question keeps changing dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing the method [`str.rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind), which is part of the standard library.

```
>>> 'aaaaa'.rfind('aa')
3
```

Comment: you forgot about character 'h' i can see 'h' in both string

Comment: when it is ("aaaaa","aa") it should return 3 but it returns 4

Answer (score 0):

```
[pos for pos, match in enumerate(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s3)) if match]
```